# Nifi: Failed to retrieve directory listing when connecting to FTP server

Tags: ftp, apache-nifi

I have a ListenFTP processor opened on a port and when i am trying to connect to it via FileZila i have an error "Failed to retrieve directory listing".
The connection seems to be establish first but then this error occurs.
[image]

Nifi is hosted on an ubuntu server running in a docker image
[image]

ListenFTP processor is opened on port 2221
[image]

I tried to change some configuration in FileZila based on this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24566692/filezilla-ftp-server-fails-to-retrieve-directory-listing) but nothing worked.

The connection works well on localhost, i can connect to the ftp server and transfer files

Somone has an idea how to solved that ?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [the documentation of the processor](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.19.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ListenFTP/additionalDetails.html), it states that

> "After starting the processor and connecting to the FTP server, an
> empty root directory is visible in the client application. Folders can
> be created in and deleted from the root directory and any of its
> subdirectories. Files can be uploaded to any directory. Uploaded files
> do not show in the content list of directories, since files are not
> actually stored on this FTP server, but converted into FlowFiles and
> transferred to the next processor via the 'success' relationship. It
> is not possible to download or delete files like on a regular FTP
> server. All the folders (including the root directory) are virtual
> directories, meaning that they only exist in memory and do not get
> created in the file system of the host machine. Also, these
> directories are not persisted: by restarting the processor all the
> directories (except for the root directory) get removed. Uploaded
> files do not get removed by restarting the processor, since they are
> not stored on the FTP server, but transferred to the next processor as
> FlowFiles."